# Inserting multiple rows of data into SQL Sever 2012 table; Table is an Invalid Object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Pretty new to SQL Server. As the title says, I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data into a table. I've had a look on here (and online elsewhere) and the code part looks correct..?

The problem I have is that the table, which exists in the DB, is apparently an 'Invalid Object', and the same is true for the columns of the table too.

```
INSERT INTO [EmployeeIDCodes] ([EmployeeForeName], [EmployeeLastName], [EmployeePosition], [EmployeeWorkLocation])
VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0),
       (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid object name 'EmployeeIDCodes'

If anyone could shed some light as to why I'm getting this error, that would be great.

Comment: Do you need to USE the relevant database?

Comment: I did originally place this at the top of the query, however it didn't do anything; Use [DB_Name] Go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure that your current context in a right database:

  ```
  USE [yourDBName];

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeIDCodes] ....
  ```
- Include schema name when your refer to table, for instance:

  ```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeIDCodes] (.....
  ```

Perhaps the table was created in another schema than dbo?